# Prioritize objects using PriorityQueue and custom comparator in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, priority-queue

I have a list of objects and a query. I need to rank the objects, based on how do they match the query. An object would match the query 100% if it contains all properties in the query. 
My program works correctly, but I have a design issue. From the console input, I have a location of a these objects. In this location I need to find all type of specific objects, and to perform the query on them. Based on the result of this query, I need t prioritize them. So from my App.class I create a `Map` between a object and set of its properties (I can't use the object directly). Then, again from the console input, I read the query. There can be many queries. For all query I create new `RankingSystem` object (which, I don't like, I don't think I should create new object for every new query), where `RankingSystem` has two fields - the query itself and the map between Object and its set of properties.

Then, for every query, which I read from the console, I create new `RankingSystem` object. Again, I don't think this is correct. However, if I put `private Set<String> query` as a parameter  then I have problems with creating a custom comparator. I thought of extracting the comparator in a separate class, yet, I do need to put there the `computeRank` method. If I do so, then I have to create the comparator with two fields (dictionary and query), because I need them for the `computeRank` method. Another thing (which stops me from creating the comparator in a separate class), is that I am using `computeRank` in the `findBestMatches` method, to print out the percentage of matches. I must print the matching percentage, so I need to have this method (`computeRank`) in the `RankingSystem` class. I am using it for my custom comparator as well, so if I extract my custom comparator in a separate class, I will have the same method twice (which is obvious code repetition, which is bad). So I decided to put the comparator inside my `RankingSystem` class. Is this approach OK, or is there a better approach? Also, is there a way to avoid the creation of an `RankingSystem` object every time when I have a new query? Here is my `RankingSystem` class:

```
    public class RankingSystem {
    private Map<File, Set<String>> dictionary;
    //Q1: is there a way to avoid putting the query as a class field? At the moment it seems as the right solution, because I need it for my custom comparator, but this way I create new object for each query?
    private Set<String> query;

    public RankingSystem(Map<File, Set<String>> dictionary, Set<String> query) {
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
        this.query = query;
    }

    private PriorityQueue<File> compareFiles(){
        PriorityQueue<File> queue = new PriorityQueue<File>(10, fileComparator);
        for(File file: dictionary.keySet()) {
            if(computeFileRank(file) != 0) {
                queue.add(file);
            }
        }
        return queue;
    }

    public void findBestMatches() {
        PriorityQueue<File> queue = compareFiles();
        if(queue.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("no matches found");
        }
        int counter = 0;
        while(!queue.isEmpty() && counter < 10) {
            File file = queue.poll();
            System.out.println(file.getName() + ":" + computeFileRank(file) + "%");
            counter++;
        }
    }

    //Q2: is it OK leaving the comparator like this? I tried to extract it into a separate class, but that way I get code repetition (of computeRank method) and I have to pass the dictionary and the query as fields again? 
    private Comparator<File> fileComparator = new Comparator<File>() {
        public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
            if (computeFileRank(f1) > computeFileRank(f2))
                return -1;
            if (computeFileRank(f1) < computeFileRank(f2))
                return 1;
            return 0;
        }       
    };

    private double computeFileRank(File file) {
        int matches = 0;
        int totalCount = query.size();
        Set<String> wordsInFile = dictionary.get(file);
        for(String word: query) {
            if(wordsInFile.contains(word)) {
                matches++;
            }
        }
        return matches*100/totalCount;
    }
}
```

Just for the sake of trying, I tried to move my custom comparator in a separate class and this is how it looks:

```
public class FileComparator implements Comparator<File>{
    //I dont like that I need to pass the query and the dictionary again
    private Set<String> query;
    private Map<File, Set<String>> dictionary;

    public FileComparator(Set<String> query, Map<File, Set<String>> dictionary) {
        this.query = query;
        this.dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        if (computeFileRank(f1, query) > computeFileRank(f2, query))
            return -1;
        if (computeFileRank(f1, query) < computeFileRank(f2, query))
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }   

    //I dont like that I have the same method on 2 places
    private double computeFileRank(File file, Set<String> query) {
        int matches = 0;
        int totalCount = query.size();
        Set<String> wordsInFile = dictionary.get(file);
        for(String word: query) {
            if(wordsInFile.contains(word)) {
                matches++;
            }
        }
        return matches*100/totalCount;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't change a question significantly after answers are available. You can always ask a follow-up question instead. I have rollbacked your changes.

Answer (score 1):

You are computing a rank 4 times here. Why not store the results in a variable and compute only 2 times?

> ```
> public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
>         if (computeFileRank(f1) > computeFileRank(f2))
>             return -1;
>         if (computeFileRank(f1) < computeFileRank(f2))
>             return 1;
>         return 0;
>     }       
> };
> ```

```
public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
        final int rank1 = computeFileRank(f1);
        final int rank2 = computeFileRank(f2);
        if (rank1 > rank2)
            return -1;
        if (rank1 < rank2)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    }       
};
```

---

Can `totalCount` be `0`? Do you want to divide by 0 or have different behavior in such case?

> ```
>  private double computeFileRank(File file, Set<String> query) {
>         // ..
>         int totalCount = query.size();
>         // ..
>         return matches*100/totalCount;
>     }
> ```